# Next step executes before REST Endpoint data received & unable to render properties of state

Tags: reactjs

In my React js application, I consume an endpoint which takes a bit longer time to respond, sometimes 1.5 seconds also (Because it takes data from Big Query). So next step executes and finally it fails to get value and renders nothing. But after the reception of response, I can find value available in console of browser.

Details:

```
axios.get(url)
        .then(function(response) {
          this.setState({ listusers: response.data });          
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error(error);
        });
```

In the render method:

```
{this.state.listusers.length ? (
 this.state.listusers.map(
     element =>  "Time Stamp: " +  element.Timestamp +  " - MacAddress: " +
                element.MacAddress +" - DeviceID: " + element.DeviceID
            )  ) : (  <p>No Data</p>      )}
```

Even with setTimeout it is not able to render.

Any way out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be returning a DOM something from the map expression, let's say:
`this.state.listusers.map(
     element => element ? <p> "foo"+element.bar+"other..." </p> : <p> no data </p>
)`

because you're only constructing a String, and not returning anything to be rendered,

also check out your ternary conditional operator syntax, I guess is not what you meant

Comment: If the rest end point returns results within 500 ms then rendering happens properly. but it us asynchronous, so when it takes more time then it assigns to state.listusers variable after 1 s  and fails to render to page.

Comment: properly declared states in components should be aware of data changes, so if state is null it renders null, but if state changes after 500ms, 1s or 1000s it should re render to show what is now in the state, that's how react works, try to debug better and find the reason why is it not working; I think it is because of what I said of not returning a DOM element and your ternary operator, try to implement my answer somehow